# how to show query that created a view in azure sql

Tags: sql, azure, t-sql, view

There are many views in my azure sql database. What is the command to get the query that was used to create the views?

I've found that for mysql it is something like show create view . But it doesn't work for azure sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get definition of all the views:

```
SELECT definition, uses_ansi_nulls, uses_quoted_identifier, is_schema_bound  
FROM sys.sql_modules
```

To get the definition of specific view :

```
SELECT definition, uses_ansi_nulls, uses_quoted_identifier, is_schema_bound  
FROM sys.sql_modules  
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('VIEW_1');
```